# Creating a scientist-only country in our world

Tags: internal-consistency, society, economy, politics

Wanting to innovate humanity, a multi-billionaire decided to start a new country. He was able to convince a country in Europe to sell a large portion of their land to him.

He then constructed advanced buildings for research purposes, and invited all scientists and engineers in the world to become citizen of his country. The only thing they will need to do is research and construct whatever they want.

Everything is provided for, including food, housing, etc. Menial tasks like cooking, maintenance, anything unrelated to science will be contracted, so those scientists will have total focus on their work. They will still be paid, though the intellectual property for their work will be handed over to the country, and then traded with the rest of the world. And to prevent freeloaders, the billionaire decided that each and every scientist must be able to contribute something within a deadline. If they fail, they will get kicked out of the country.

**What are the biggest challenges for a science-based country to exist? Is it even possible in our current world?**

Comment: Not exactly what you describe, but it somewhat fits - naturally - Switzerland.

Comment: How are deadlines decided? Are they set by the millionaire or some comitee reviewing every project, or are invited scientists free to set their own deadline as well?

Comment: Oh wow, I'll definitely take a look at the economics of Switzerland now.

Comment: How do you trade your inventions back to the other countries? If through the patents, you will need a population of lawyers in addition to the population of scientists. You can check how companies like Qualcomm operate to see the perils of this approach.

Comment: *"What are the biggest challenges for a science-based country to exist?"* People hate science.

Comment: Is there a fundamental difference between your contractors delivering meals and the scientists?  Both seem to be contracted to do a task, but the scientists are somehow different.  Exploring the differences may lead you to many pitfalls in the structure.

Comment: While I appreciate your enthusiasm for my answer, I want to encourage you to wait before choosing a best answer (the checkmark).  It's been less than an hour since you asked it.  Give it until the weekend and see what answers you've got.  You can upvote every answer you like (and please do!).  If you choose a best answer too quickly, it discourages others from answering.  And there are lots of great ideas out there.  You might like one better than mine.  Or maybe not.  Either way, I'm sure you want to hear them.

Comment: It might also be useful to ask yourself: why (aside from ego) does your hypothetical billionaire want to create a *state* for scientific research, and not simply a *company*? There are plenty of current and historical examples of that approach - right now it's trendy for private spaceflight, for instance.

Comment: I think this has been done, country is New Mexico, government is the billionaires, what is produced is the atomic bomb, among other things.

Comment: The biggest issue would still be money. Scientists producing Patents is a good thing. Useful, marketable patents are rare.

Comment: "*Menial tasks ... will be contracted*".  So, it's **not** a "*scientist-only country*".

Comment: One state *ceding sovereignty over a territory* to a non-state billionaire in order to create a new boutique state seems very unrealistic. Example: Bill Gates could own a lot of land in Denmark, under the Danish flag, without issue. However, Denmark would never sign an international treaty with Bill Gates, recognizing him as an equal, as a monarch of a country, and ceding that country some of their formerly-Danish territory. States fight bloody wars to prevent *any* encroachment by other states - millions died in World War I for less.

Comment: Your concept is similar to main corporate campuess of Apple, Microsoft or Google. They have a ton of scientists and engineers, they could build housing for them on site, and all their innovations belong to the company.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Your Premise Can Not Work**

> Menial tasks like cooking, maintenance, anything unrelated to science
>   will be contracted.

How does that work exactly?  Do you fly in a team of people to clean houses once a week?  Does the laundry go out by train across the border and back again?  Or do you have large numbers of second-class citizens (or people not even granted citizenship) living in your country?

Every time any locality has ever created a "noble" class (whether it's actual nobles or a collection of valued people at a large workplace), there is always a support team.  A team that almost always vastly outnumbers the nobles.

**NASA**

Let's take the National Aeronautics and Space Administration (United States) as an example.  Their complexes are huge and they often build nearby housing complexes for their workers.  You can easily imagine a small country entirely populated by groups such as NASA where everything revolves around them.

> [Who Works for NASA?](https://www.nasa.gov/audience/forstudents/5-8/features/nasa-knows/what-is-nasa-58.html)
>  NASA’s Headquarters is in Washington, D.C. The
>   agency has nine centers, the Jet Propulsion Laboratory and seven test
>   and research facilities located in several states around the country.
>   More than 17,000 people work for NASA. Many more people work with the
>   agency as government contractors. These people are hired by companies
>   that NASA pays to do work. The combined workforce represents a variety
>   of jobs. Astronauts may be the best-known NASA employees, but they
>   only represent a small number of the total workforce. Many NASA
>   workers are scientists and engineers. But people there hold many other
>   jobs, too, from secretaries to writers to lawyers to teachers.

Of the [17,211 people working for NASA in 2015](https://www.nasa.gov/sites/default/files/files/NASA_FY_2016_Budget_Estimates.pdf) (page SD-6), 7788 (45%) are in a category called "Safety, Security, and Mission Services."  Those are the folks not working for a particular department and are doing janitorial, security, landscape, tradework (like HVAC, plumbing, electrical), transportation, food service, and a whole variety of non-science jobs.

Within other categories like Science or Aeronautics, we see numbers of people, but you know a large portion of them are clerical, secretarial, or management, and not doing actual science.

Then there are the people who care for where the scientists are when they're not at work.  Who builds and maintains the housing?  What about grocery stores, restaurants, movie theaters, ice skating rinks?  Do the scientists have families?  Are all of their spouses scientists too?  What about their children?  Do they go to school?  Who is teaching them...and providing support services for the teachers?  Who takes care of the children if they're too young to be in school or outside of school hours, if both parents are working their science jobs?  What about transportation around the country?  School buses?  Commuting to work?  Moving around and between the huge job centers?

The outwardly valued people of NASA are scientists and astronauts.  But they are a minority of the total workers.  It takes a lot of people to form the village (to coin a phrase) that allows the science to happen.

What happens to all those people who are not scientists in your "scientist-only" world?

If your question is, can a county make its only export be the products of scientific research, the answer is sure.  Under the right conditions.  But your stated question is about making a country (not a town or or a company, but a full country) that where the only citizens are scientists and engineers and even their citizenship is conditional, based on their work output.  Is *that* possible?  No, it is not.

Comment: Wow, thank you so much for that! I severely underestimated the premise of such a country. I was only thinking that it was already a sustainable country, and instead thinking about outside forces like other countries, how will they react, etc. But your answers basically states that such a country would be impossible, which I completely agree now. Will work on the premise a little further.

Comment: From what I understand what Cyn is saying is that your country wouldn't comprise only scientists and that it would be impossible to exclude from citizenship the other workers. Cyn doesn't say why though.

Comment: I didn't say it was impossible.  I said that Basher did not mention this in her/his question but it's a huge consideration.  Either you have a large majority of citizens that are not citizens (which violates the premise of the question) or you have a large majority of residents who are not citizens (which occurs in the real world, past and present, but is an ethical and political nightmare).  You absolutely can not built this world without dealing with this question front and center.

Answer (score 4):

I'd say this question is *definitely* opinion-based, but the following issues would likely arise:

- Unless the Supreme Potentate can clearly define what "something" is, a lot of people (scientists and engineers are people too!) will be leery of working on that kind of contract.  Moreover, science is a process, not a pachinko machine.  Is validation of another scientist's experiment "something"?  Is experimentation that validates the null hypothesis "something"?
- "Multi-billionaire" vastly underestimates the amount of money many fields of research require.  If you wanted useful particle physics or astrophysics research in your country of scientists, that would *rapidly* eat up any private individual's wealth.  That's *why* countries fund the stuff.
- Where do all of the contractors live?  If you're contracting maintenance and food prep, you also then have to feed the contractors, and your support infrastructure is going to vastly outnumber your Citizen-Scientists.  If none of these people are granted the rights of citizens, you're very likely going to have a workers' revolt in a hurry.
- If you're contracting out defense and policing too, you're paying armed contractors.  That, historically, doesn't go well.

The problems go on, and on, and on - there's a reason that such a society hasn't come to be in the real world.

Comment: Excellent feedback. The "something" part could be solved by giving a goal to achieve, like "A way to create a sustainable moon base" and thus, having each person form a team that will contribute to that goal. Though, teaming up means there should be an organization or committee that will handle them. Financially, I was thinking if its possible that other countries or companies "request" technological improvements and will pay for it. But again, this involves more people that aren't technically scientist and are lawyers or administrations.

Comment: It goes beyond that - if you want robust science done, you need people who _aren't_ contributing directly to whatever's being done.  You need technicians, who are adept at reading plans and making them into things.  You need scientists whose job it is to peer review others' work, outside of the context of whatever the goal might be.

Comment: It very clearly is:
"And to prevent freeloaders, the billionaire decided that each and every scientist must be able to contribute *something* within a deadline."

Comment: And you need people to clean the toilets.

Comment: @Cyn "They come to [ScienceTopia] thinking they're gonna be captains of industry, but they all forget that somebody's gotta scrub the toilets." -- F. Fontaine.

Comment: "Armed contractors" = mercenaries

Comment: @nzaman - yup.  and the problem with mercenaries is you can't really _stop_ paying them, not unless you have someone else to stop _them_.

Comment: The problem with mercenaries is that historically they've been for sale to the higher bidder